# Kendo Ui opensource Grid not refresh in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, kendo-grid

I try to auto refresh my Kendo Grid per 10 seconds. It works in Google Chrome and Firefox, perfectly. However, it's not work in Internet Explorer. Also refresh button which is on the right-bottom of grid, it's not work when I click in Internet explorer. But It's work in Chrome and Firefox. What should I do for Internet Explorer?

```
function handleDataFromServer() {
            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
}
window.setInterval("handleDataFromServer()", 10000);
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                sortable: true,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true,
                    buttonCount: 5,
                    pageSizes: true
                },
                autoBind: true,
                dataSource: {
                    pageSize: 15,
                    transport: {
                        read: "/reports/Getdata",
                        type: "json"
                    }, schema: {
                        data: "data",
                        total: "total"
                    },
                    serverPaging:true
                },
.....
```

EDIT : `handleDataFromServer()` function is work in Internet Explorer. but `$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();` is not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be solved by disabling caching. I ran into this same issue and this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29486210/2600073) fixed my same issue. Basically you need to:

```
...
transport: {
    read: {
        url: "/reports/Getdata",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json"
    }
},
...
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

What if you put an alert() statement inside the handleDataFromServer function? Is it invoked? If it is please demonstrate your case with a JsBin example.

Here is what I tried and it works fine:

[JsBin](http://jsbin.com/qebiwati/1/edit)

Comment: I put alert and its invoked.

Comment: my codes is worked in JsBin  but it still not refresh in visual studio internet explorer.